# PhpMyAdmin versus Script (Load Data Infile)

Tags: mysql

If I run the following query in the SQL box from PhpMyAdmin:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/sveiv/public_html/testload.txt' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

everything works fine.

If I run the following script (testload.php)

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','dbname');

$conn->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/sveiv/public_html/testload.txt' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'");
?>
```

nothing happens.

PS: The connection to the database has been established successfully.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','db_name');

$conn->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/sveiv/public_html/testload.txt' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'");

Comment: *nothing happens* Impossible. `$conn->query` must return something at least... is it TRUE? if not - what error occured? And - does the account used for a connection have FILE privilege? Does session secure_priv variable is not set?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. The customer service told me I have FILE privileges for using LOAD DATA INFILE without the option LOCAL. I belive they are right since the SQL query in PhpMyAdmin works fine.

Comment: How can I get the error code for the query?

Comment: *The customer service told me* So you're trying to do it on a REMOTE server? Now think - where PHP will search `'/home/sveiv/public_html/testload.txt'`? Do you really think it will search it on YOUR station and not on its own host?

Comment: Thank you for your help Akina! The customer service solved the issue. There was nothing wrong with the code.